# Seeking Calendar on JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Does anyone know similar calendar as in the picture below (see url), just do it on Java Script or JQuery? Must need the opportunity to choose by the hour and day. Thank you!

[link text](http://www.avatariya.ru/time-targeting.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your picture doesn't work, but one good date picker that supports both date and time (and the only one known to me) is [this one](http://home.jongsma.org/software/js/datepicker).

[Here](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/) is a good list of jQuery calendar controls.

Comment: Link works, look ink text!
I just want the hours and days of the week ONLY, and the date picker numbers of the month (dates), it is not good for me.

Comment: @Vlad ah, I didn't see the link. Maybe this one could be a basis: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/